# Find the order of $2$ in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/151\ \mathbb Z)^{\times}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> What is the order of $2$ in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/151\ \mathbb Z)^{\times}\ $?

By some calculation I found that $\text {ord}\ (2) = 15.$ Is there any systematic way to find the order? First of all the order should divide $150.$ Hence it is one of the numbers $:$

$$1,2,3,5,6,10,15,25,30,50,75,150.$$

If the orders were too big then it is very difficult to find the order by hand. Could anyone please give me some suggestion in this regard?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It's an example of the discrete logarithm problem, which is known to be difficult. A google search will produce many references to confirm this.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answers that have been posted, Rabin?

Answer (score 3):

For that example, I might do it this way (all calculations modulo $151$):

$2^2=4$. $2^3=8$.
$2^5=4\times8=32$.
$2^6=8^2=64$.
$2^{10}=32^2=1024=118=-33$.
$2^{15}=32\times(-33)=-1056=1$, done.

If I had needed to go farther, I'd have $2^{25}=2^{10}\times2^{15}$; $2^{30}=(2^{15})^2$; $2^{50}=(2^{25})^2$; $2^{75}=2^{25}\times2^{50}$.

Answer (score 2):

Or with a bit of machinery: Note that $151\equiv -1\pmod{8}$, so $2$ is a quadratic residue.  This means we only need to consider
$$
1,3,5,15,25,75.
$$
Clearly 1, 3 or 5 won't work, and so compute $2^{15}$ either by repeating square
$$
2^{16}=(((2^2)^2)^2)^2=256^2=105^2=11025=2$$
so $2^{15}=1$, or note that
$$
\frac{2^{15}-1}{2^5-1}=2^{10}+2^5+1=1057=7\times 151.
$$